# Plotting equipotentials line of a Julia set in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, dynamic, complex, scripting

I need to plot the equipotential lines of the Julia sets of the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-1$ by using Mathematica, but I don't have a good background in programming.

Given $f$, with *equipotential lines* I mean the contour lines of the form $\vert \phi \vert=\text{const.}$ where $\phi$ is the Boettcher coordinate at infinity.

I have tried to analyse the only script I found online to plot the external rays.

```
jsp = JuliaSetPlot[theC, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 
      1}}];
jb = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, 
     JuliaSetBoettcher[theC, x + I y, MaxIterations -> 30]}, {y, -1, 
     1, .005}, {x, -2, 2, .005}], 
   1]; (*Flatten serve per unire delle liste; *)
theRays = Array[# &, 20, {-Pi, Pi}];
rayTable = 
  Table[theRayPoints = 
    Select[jb, (theta - 0.0001) < Arg[#[[3]]] < (theta + 0.0001) &];
   Graphics@Line@({#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ theRayPoints), {theta, 
    theRays}];
Show[{jsp, rayTable}]
```

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to plot the equipotentials.

EDIT:
I manage to plot something by using this code:

```
ArrayPlot[
 Table[Sin[10 Abs@JuliaSetBoettcher[-1, x + I*y]], {y, -3, 
   3, .01}, {x, -3, 3, .01}]]
```

and I obtained the image below. However, this is not enough for me as I want to plot the contour lines.

[image]

Comment: @rhermans I'm sorry. I have edited my post, and I hope that it is fine now.

Comment: Cartesio, thanks for taking the [tour] and improving your question. This is much more likely to be well received and inspire a good answer. I have changed my vote. Nice work.